# CakePHP 2.x theme not showing properly

Tags: php, cakephp, themes, cakephp-2.4

I have a `CakePHP 2.4` project I am working on trying to fix, and I can't seem to get the theme to properly display. There is one theme built out, just not showing. When I log the name of the  theme for testing, the correct theme name is set, in the controller action, and also during  `beforeFilter` and `afterFilter` execution.

So it appears as though it is loading the correct theme, however the `default` theme still shows. What should I test next to try and fix this?

...Edited for comment below:

From `AppController`:

```
/**
 * App Theme
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $theme = 'themename';

/**
 * beforeFilter callback
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->_authSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked the theme's naming is correct?

Have you checked the theme's file structure matches your app/view/... structure?

If you are calling the theme with before filter in the app controller have you checked you are calling this in as a parent filter in any before filters in your other controllers?

Comment: Yes. The only difference being I do not have the theme set in `AppController::beforeFilter`, but right before it. It is the same way the default install shows it. See edit above.